# SVN ignoring hidden files (.project .pydevproject and . files)

Tags: svn, ignore, svnignore

I want to ignore some hidden files (like .project and .pydevproject) in SVN. They are already in our trunk at the moment so I don't want to delete them from the trunk since it may cause more problems for the other developers. So what I tried to do is to run:

```
svn propset svn:ignore .project .
```

but right after that when I run svn status, it returns:

```
M .
```

and if I make changes on .project, it still tracks those changes. I also tried global-ignores in /etc/subversion/config, no luck.

What do you think would be the best way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`svn:ignore` works only for the files that haven't been added yet.

Unfortunately you cannot do that in automatic way (at least I don't know any way of doing that).

So all you can do now is:

1. Delete files from repository with `svn rm`
2. Ask developers to store files somewhere before their next `svn up`
3. They run `svn up` and move the deleted files back

Now `.project` is not tracked by svn and will not appear in `svn st`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What about the "." file? When I set svn:ignore, "." file being modified, I couldn't figure out what should I do about that.

Comment: That's because the svn:ignore property has been set on the "." folder. You have to commit this to apply your ignore configuration.